# Fixed points and Stability (Nonlinear System)

Tags: nonlinear-system

> $$\dot x = -x + x^3$$
>   $$\dot y = x + y$$
>   Where $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R^2}$

I found the fixed points to be:

$$(0,0),(0,1),(0,-1),(1,0),(1,1),(1,-1),(-1,0),(-1,1),(-1,-1)$$

The Jacobian Matrix to be:

\begin{bmatrix}
 -1+3x^2   & 0\\  
 1           & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}

But every point is unstable.

What am i doing wrong? I feel like:

1) I have too many fixed points and

2) My Jacobian matrix is wrong

Thanks.

Comment: i have edited the equations in LaTeX .

Comment: @Jon: I only find three critical points at $$(x, y) = (-1, 1), (0, 0), (1, -1)$$. The Jacobian is correct and all three critical points are unstable. Draw a phase portrait to see these.

Comment: @Jon: Stationary points occur when $\dot{x}=0$ and $\dot{y}=0$. You should get $(0,0)$, $(1, -1)$ and $(-1, 1)$. The Jacobian looks correct.

Comment: Thanks you both. I see what I did wrong. I appreciate the feedback.